# Cannot read property 'submit' of null i use laravel and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to add a product to my favorites, but I do not want to make a load for the entire page, so I use JavaScript as shown in the code where I made an ancor disruption and created a form and took an id from the form and implemented it by using the submit function, but the following error appears and does
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
Please advise the importance
Thank you

**this view**

```
<div class="product-info">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                        <!-- Start Single Tab -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="man" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="tab-single">
                                <div class="row">
                                    @foreach($products as $p)
                                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
                                        <form action="{{route('cart.store')}}" method="post" id="add-cart-{{$p->id}}">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$p->id}}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="Product_Name_ar" value="{{$p->Product_Name_ar}}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="Price" value="{{$p->Price}}">
                                        <div class="single-product">
                                            <div class="product-img">
                                                <a href="{{route('product', ['product' => $p->id])}}">
                                                    <img class="default-img" src="{{ asset('images/products/'.$p->image) }}" alt="#">
                                                    <img class="hover-img" src="{{ asset('images/products/'.$p->image) }}" alt="#">
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="button-head">
                                                    <div class="product-action">

                                                        @if(Auth::guard('customer')->check())
                                                            <span class="favorite-count">{{ $p->favorite_to_customers->count() }}</span>
                                                        <a title="Wishlist" href="javascript:void (0);" onclick="document.getElementById('favorite-{{$p->id}}').submit()" class="{{  Auth::guard('customer')->user()->favorite_products()->where('product_id', $p->id)->count() != 0 ? 'favorite' : ''  }}">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-heart "></i><span>Add to Favorite</span></a>
                                                            <form id="favorite-{{$p->id}}" action="{{route('product.favorite', $p->id)}}" method="post">
                                                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                                            </form>
                                                        @else
                                                            <span  class="favorite-count">{{ $p->favorite_to_customers->count() }}</span>
                                                            <a title="Wishlist" href="javascript:void (0);" onclick="toastr.info('To add favorite list you to need login first', 'info', {
                                                                closeButton: true,
                                                                progressBar: true
                                                            })">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-heart "></i>
                                                                <span>Add to Favorite</span></a>
                                                        @endif


                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="product-action-2">
                                                        <button style="background: transparent; border: none; color: black" class="btn btn-warning">Add to chart</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product-content">
                                                <h3><a href="product-details.html">{{ $p->Product_Name_ar }}</a></h3>
                                                <div class="product-price">
                                                    <span>{{ $p->Price }} K.D</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                   @endforeach

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/ End Single Tab -->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**This Controller**

```
class Favoritecontroller extends Controller
{
    public function add($id) {
       $customer = Auth::guard('customer')->user();

       $isFavorite = $customer->favorite_products()->where('product_id', $id)->count();
       if($isFavorite == 0) {
           $customer->favorite_products()->attach($id);
       }else {
           $customer->favorite_products()->detach($id);
       }
return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:customer']], function () {
    Route::post('favorite/{id}/add', 'FavoriteController@add')->name('product.favorite');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your JS fails here

```
... onclick="document.getElementById('favorite-{{$p->id}}').submit()"
```

**The proper way to do it**

```
... onclick="addToWhishList({{$p->id}})"
```

Then in your JS

```
<script>
function addToWhishList(formId) {
  //console.log(formId);
  document.getElementById('favorite-' + formId).submit();
}
</script>
```

Check working [Demo](https://repl.it/repls/MintcreamApprehensiveDictionaries)

Comment: Same Problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    at addToWhishList ((index):1428)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):411)
addToWhishList @ (index):1428
onclick @ (index):411